# The output returns in string format and not int. Eg: the function returns "1563.7383" instead of 1563.7383

Tags: output-formatting

```
def polysum(n,s):
    import math
    r = math.pi/n
    area = ((0.25)*n*(s**2))/ math.tan(r)
    per = n*s
    total = area + (per**2)
    return ("%.4f" % total)
```

The output returns in string format and not int. Eg: the function returns "1563.7383" instead of  1563.7383

Comment: When asking a question related to code, it's always a good idea to add a tag for that language. Can you [edit] to do so? While you're at it, you could also make an effort to format your code (select it, and then hit Ctrl+K or the `{}` button on the toolbar) so that it's readable. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You did not add a language tag in your question, but judging from the syntax I would assume it is Python here.

First, note that 1563.7383 *cannot* be `int`, but it can be `float`.

Your problem is in your usage of `"%.4f" % total`, which converts `total` to a string with 4 decimal places.

You should probably just return `total` in your function (i.e. treat it as a `float`, without rounding, throughout your program). Only round it off using `"%.4f" % total` when you are actually outputting the value.

Alternatively, if you absolutely must round off the value in your function and have it as a `float`, consider using the built-in function [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) instead. Your usage would then be `return round(total, 4)`